# Which is the answer? Why?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> We were so sure that Jerry _____ well on the difficult job. His past experience in
>   other work showed he was the right guy for it. So when he failed, no one believed it.

Options to fill the gap are:
(A) had done
(B) did
(C) has done
(D) would do

I think (A),(B) and (D) all are correct. Can someone help?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if your title gives an idea about the content of the question? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

The last sentence says:

> So when he failed, no one believed it.

That means that they thought he'd do well, but then he *later* failed. They didn't think he *had done* well. That might have been correct if the last sentence said:

> When we realized he had failed, no one believed it.

That's why the answer is D.

> We were so sure that Jerry *would do* well on the difficult job. His past experience in other work showed he was the right guy for it. So when he failed, no one believed it.

Comment: Can't one use the simple past "did" to describe the past fact on Jerry doing well on the difficult job. The whole context still makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. The meaning of the passage is that, before Jerry started the task, people had expected him to succeed, but when he attempted it he failed. So his doing well is _not_ a 'past fact'.